# extracting values from Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am confused about how to extract values from a query, and place them into specific variable, when i don't know before hand what the name of the value will be.

it might be easier to show you what i mean.

the images below are the returned values, grouped by heading  i.e Total_responded, Percent_responded etc.

[image: image from mysql database]

so the first row will have under the column Responce the value **Poached** with a **Percent_responded** of 16.66667.

however the next row will have under column  **Responce** $scrambled with a **Percent_responded** of 83.333333

i now want to place each of these values into individual variables like:

```
$poached , $poachedPercentage, $scrambled, $scrambledPercentage etc
```

i attempted to do it below, but produced the wrong figures. this is also not a cost effective way to do it. so, i would really appricaite some advice on how to extract the values

```
$getPollResult   = results();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($getResult , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{

$responce  =   safe_output(round($row['RESPONCE']));

$percentage = safe_output(round($row['Percent_responded']));


if($responce  = 'Poached')
{
  $percentageOne = $percentage;
  $poached =     $responce;          
}
if ($responce = 'Scrambled')
{
    $percentageTwo = $percentage;
    $scrambled =     $responce;

}    
 //  echo " $percentagePoached      $percentageScrambled ";die();
}
```

Comment: Inside the if, you should use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Why do you use `round()` on a string value `safe_output(round($row['RESPONCE']));`? This will set `$responce` equal to `0`.

Comment: What is `safe_output()`?

Comment: i thought you wanted to "place them into specific variable, when i don't know before hand what the name of the value will be". that's why i am a bit confused why you didn't pay attention to my answer which exactly solves this problem. plus you accepted another answer which doesn't take care of what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$responce = trim($row['RESPONCE']);
```

Instead Of

```
$responce = safe_output(round($row['RESPONCE']));
```

> Also, Change in if condition `=` to `==`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "variable variables" ([PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)) to achieve that:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($getResult , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $responce_name  =  trim($row['RESPONCE']);
    $percentage_name = $responce_name . "Percentage";
    $percentage = safe_output(round($row['Percent_responded'])); //don't know what safe_output() does

    $$percentage_name = $percentage; //notice the double "$" here
}
```

your PHP variables will then look like this:

```
$PoachedPercentage = 17;
$ScrambledPercentage = 83;
// and so on....
```